# Placeholder attribute. to e.g. or not to e.g.

Tags: html, user-interface, placeholder

Is it clearer to do the following:

> placeholder="e.g. Chequing"

or is

> placeholder="Chequing"

good enough

Answer (score 3):

If the input has a label, the placeholder text can give an example of the expected input. Preferably, it will let the user know that it is one of many possible values by using "e.g., [value]".

If the input does not have a label the placeholder text is most useful if it says what the input is for, for example, "Email Address".

Comment: + 1 for the info regarding usage without a label... never really paid much attention to that but it makes sense